# simple horizontal line with gradient effect in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have tried below code this works but i need shadow like effect for line .

```
 <View
             style={{
                borderBottomColor: 'grey',
                borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
                marginBottom: 15,
                marginTop: 50,
                margin: 10,
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will render a shadow for you in the view.

```
<View
                 style={{
                    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
                    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
                    marginBottom: 15,
                    marginTop: 50,
                    margin: 10,
           shadowOffset: {
                width: 2,
                height: 2,
            },
            shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
            shadowOpacity: 0.5,
            shadowRadius: 10,
                  }}
                />
```

But as you said you want gradient then you might need to add this library : 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient